# Google service account: Delegate Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority to impersonate only ONE user

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

We need to access Google Calendar API with server application to create the events and invite the attendees. Google recommends to use service account for the applications.

The main problem here with the attendees inviting to the event, because the service account can't do it without the Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority (see image).

Organization do not want to give the service account an access to ALL user's data. So, I'm trying to find out can we delegate the Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority to the ONE user of the domain ? (restrict access to use another user's data).

P.S. it's only about Google Calendar API.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what it meant to as to use a service account to access the Google Calendar API on behalf of users, is that you can use a single service account to impersonate different users one at a time. So if you want to impersonate just only one user, then there shouldn't be any problem. You just need to specify the user's email address to impersonate before making an authorized API call

After you [delegate domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority), You need to  [preparation to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) where you need to specify the user to impersonate.

For example, if you will check [Google APIs Client Library for Java - Impersonation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/master/docs/oauth-2.0.md#impersonation), [GoogleCredential.Builder.setServiceAccountUser(String)](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.Builder.html#setServiceAccountUser-java.lang.String-). This method only accept a single email address of the user to impersonate.

[image]

---

**OPTION 1: (With the use of a service account)**

If you want to use a service account in your application which can only impersonate a specific user/users, you can publish an app in [Google Apps Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/overview). Then you can restrict the access of this app for specific user/users or even by organization using admin console. [Turn on or off a Google Workspace Marketplace app for users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172931?hl=en&ref_topic=1056395)

---

**OPTION 2: (Without the use of a service account)**

You can access Google API through a specific user rather than with a service account. You just need to enable the API and generate API Keys. See [Calendar API Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview?hl=en#quickstarts) on how to setup and use the api.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the response! 
Business wants to restrict an access to use all users from the domain. The service account can use only one user, which will be specified.
Can I restrict service account to use all users except one (with google)?

Comment: It is not possible to restrict a service account to impersonate specific users, as long as you have the generated key and the json file to use the service account, you can impersonate any user. I updated my answer with the available options that you might want to consider.

Comment: I'm curious how you mean you can allow a specific user and use API keys when API keys are considered anonymous.

Comment: You just need to setup the api for a specific user to use calendar api. For example you have user1@domain.com, use that particular user and enable calendar api by following the [Calendar API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview?hl=en#quickstarts) for that particular person